# C++ Input/Output stream

Tags: c++, iostream

I have a problem with I/O streams in C++. I have to write a program which reads data from a file and writes to another file. The command in CMD should be like:

```
program < file1 > file2
```

The names of the files should be provided by the user (could be random).

I've written some code, but it's not correct. I don't know how to redirect the stream to a file using the command `> file2`.

What can I change in my code to make it work? Can somebody help me?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input_line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input_line)) {
        std::ofstream output_file("file2.txt", std::ios::app);
        if (!output_file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        output_file << input_line << std::endl;
        output_file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `output_file` with `std::cout`.  Many operating systems can redirect output, but redirecting a file is a bit more difficult.  Your command line would look like:  `program < file1 > file2.txt`

Comment: Just write to `std::cout`: the redirection is performed by the shell.

Comment: *"I've written a code but it's not correct."* -- Why? What is the symptom that you observed?

Comment: *"The names of the files should be provided by the user"* -- and yet, you've hardcoded `"file2.txt"`. It is good to replace user input with hardcoded values when possible, but then your text should be updated to match.

Comment: Does this work (untested)? `std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();`

Comment: I don't have an idea how I can repalce output_file with std::cout . How can I open the file to write?

Comment: Aside from other comments, why would you reopen the output stream on each loop iteration?

Comment: Do you expect the program to be executed by `program < file1 > file2` or by `program file1 file2`?  There seems to be a discrepancy between the code and the problem statement.

Comment: "*I don't have an idea how I can repalce `output_file` with `std::cout`. How can I open the file to write?*" - you don't need to open the file yourself when using `> file2`, the command shell will handle that for you. `> file2` *redirects* `stdout` to write to `file2` for you, and `std::cout` writes to `stdout` by default. Just like `< file1` *redirects* `stdin` to read from `file1` and `std::cin` reads from `stdin` by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a problem with I/O streams in c++.

OK.

> Command in CMD should be like: "program < file1 > file2"

This implies you are using the shell to do the work. Here. The `<` and `>` are shell "operators" to redirect files to standard in and standard out of the program. This means your program should read from `std::cin` and write to `std::cout`.

You assume the output file is "file2.txt"!

```
std::ofstream output_file("file2.txt", std::ios::app);
```

You are always appending to it. If the file already exists, this may not be what you want, as it will add the new content onto any old content. I would probably change that (if I was using files). But the simpler solution is to use `std::cout` (as indicated above).

I am assuming you are doing this as part of an exercise, so going through the steps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string input_line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input_line)) {


        // This should open file is inside the loop. 
        // You should probably move it outside the loop.
        // A side effects of this is that you don't need to append
        // so you will destroy the old content and get rid of it.
        std::ofstream output_file("file2.txt", std::ios::app);

        if (!output_file.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Error" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        // probably don't want to use `std::endl` here.
        // This forces a flush from the internal buffer to the hardware.
        // You probably just want to use `"\n"` here.
        output_file << input_line << std::endl;

        // You are closing the output file after writting one line to it.
        // May be more effecient to only close the file after writting
        // all the lines to the file.
        output_file.close();
     }

    return 0;
}
```

If I was writing this for a class that was trying to understand streams. This is how I would re-write more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    std::string input_line;

    // Use a while loop to read a line from the input.
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input_line)) {

        // If the read worked the we write line back to the
        // output.
        std::cout << input_line << "\n";
    }

    // When the read (std::getline()) fails the loop
    // will not be entered. So you can stop the loop
    // and end up here.

    // Optional return at the end of main.
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This is not quite perfect as the last line may not include a new line character, but the code above always add a newline to every line. I leave it as an exercise for you to solve this last simple issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dictate the filenames from the command line then you don't really need the '<' and '>' redirectors. You could just state the names of the files and use the `int main( int argc, char * argv[] )` form of program.

Thus:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   if ( argc != 3 )
   {
      cerr << "Correct usage is myprog.exe infile outfile";
      return 1;
   }

   ifstream in( argv[1] );
   if ( !in )
   {
      cerr << "Input file not found";
      return 1;
   }

   ofstream out( argv[2] );
   for ( string line; getline( in, line); ) out << line << '\n';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `using namespace std;`

Comment: You are also not validating that `out` was able to create/open the output file before writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Files are just streams, so implement a copy function in terms of `std::istream&` and `std::ostream&`. This allows you to avoid file (location) problems during testing, use a `std::istringstream` for testing (instead of `std::ifstream`). And similar instead of `std::ofstream` you can use `std::cout` as output.

Also, learn to write functions with readable names.

It will become something like this:

```
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream input_file
{
   "Line 1 : One\n"
   "Line 2 : Two\n"
   "Line 3 : Three\n"
   "Line 4 : Four\n"
};    

void copy(std::istream& is, std::ostream& os)
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(is, line)) os << line << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    copy(input_file, std::cout);
}
```